# how to read an image with opencv using path variable in Python

Tags: python, string, opencv, imread

So I have a variable that holds the image path as a string. but I get the below error while trying to read the image using the path variable. The path variable is coming from another function that calls this code.

Error:

`can't open/read file: check file path/integrity`

My code:

```
path = "D://dev//py_scripts//SS1.jpg"
image=cv2.imread(path)
```

Tried several solutions but ended up with same error.

Comment: Is it a jpg, JPEG, or png image?

Comment: **double forward slashes**, makes the path invalid. double *back*slashes are actually single backslashes, but the string syntax requires escaping them, so that's why one has to use double backslashes... or use r-strings

Answer (score 2):

**Double forward** slashes make the path **invalid**.

Use *single* forward slashes. That is commonly *tolerated* on Windows, which natively wants **backslashes**.

Double *back*slashes are only what you *see*. They're actually single backslashes in the *path*/string, but the string syntax requires escaping backslashes (and other stuff) by a preceding backslash, so that's why one has to use double backslashes in most string literals...

Python has "r-strings" ("raw" strings). In a raw string, even backslashes are taken literally, and nothing is escapable (a matching quote character ends the string, always).

```py
"D:/dev/py_scripts/SS1.jpg"
r"D:\dev\py_scripts\SS1.jpg"
"D:\\dev\\py_scripts\\SS1.jpg"
```

Comment: Nicely explained. 

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest changing the format of the path as follows:

```
import cv2

#Several options
path = r"D:\dev\py_scripts\SS1.jpg"
path = r"D:/dev/py_scripts/SS1.jpg"
path = "D:/dev/py_scripts/SS1.jpg"
image=cv2.imread(path)
```

But based on the error you are getting, you need to check the `format` of the image and its **integrity**, as the error says. That means you must be able to open the image without issues on an editor like *Windows Photos* to check if the file is not corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

```
import cv2
path1= "SS1.jpg" 
#sometimes doesnt work depends on the compiler. If its on sub folder #py_scripts\SS1.jpg

or 

path2= "d:\dev\py_scripts\SS1.jpg"

image = cv2.imread(path2)
```

If you want to use path1 method, and set it to work 100%

```
import os
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

Comment: I downvote answers that are wrong, misleading, or not useful (the literal alt-text of the downvote button). I stand by that. see this as a signal to consider a moment longer before posting answers.